# Java - restrict scanner to accept only doubles

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Okay, so I just started learning to code and got stuck quite fast. I have multiple problems and I'm new to here, so I'll just post my code multiple times with different questions.

My problem: I want an user to input a `double` after the `System.out.println("Define your height in centimetres.");` and `System.out.println("Define your weight in kilograms.");`. I want my code to restrict it so that it is possible only to input double and nothing else in a similar way an user can't input anything else than male/female (and derivations) in the first part of my program. From what I've learned so far, I could catch an exception. First, it didn't work for me every time I tried that, second, I want my program to work in a way no exception can even happen. Is that possible? I can't really find a solution.

I started learning by trying to do a simple BMI meter. Let's just ignore the fact that values for male and female are the same, I'm gonna change that in the future. 
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
class BMI_a {   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String answer;
  do {
   double  weight, height;
   String sex;
   String Stare = System.getProperty("user.name");

   System.out.println("... BMI meter v.0.0.25 ...");
   System.out.println("Welcome to the program " + Stare + "!");

   boolean sexgood = false;
   Scanner sexscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Define your gender. (Male/Female)");
    do {
     sex = sexscanner.next();
      if(sex.equals("Male") || sex.equals("male") || sex.equals("M") || sex.equals("m")) {
       sexgood = true;
      }
      else if(sex.equals("Female") || sex.equals("female") || sex.equals("F") || sex.equals("f")) {
       sexgood = true;
      }  
      else {
       System.out.println("Did you get it right? Choose either 'Male' or 'Female'. You can also use M/F.");
      }
    }
    while (!sexgood);

   Scanner heightscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Define your height in centimetres."); 
   height = heightscanner.nextDouble();

   Scanner weightscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Define your weight in kilograms.");
   weight = weightscanner.nextDouble();

   double readier = weight / ((height * height) / (100 * 100));
   System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + readier);
   System.out.println("Normal BMI is between 18.5 and 24.9");
   if (sex.equals("Male") || sex.equals("male") || sex.equals("M") || sex.equals("m"))  {
    if (readier <= 18.5){
     System.out.println("You're probably gonna die of malnutrition soon. Go grab a snack.");
    }
    else if (readier <= 24.9) {
     System.out.println("You're fit and ready to get fat.");
    }
    else if (readier <= 29.9) {
     System.out.println("You're already quite fat. put that chocolate back!");
    }
    else {
     System.out.println("Oh boy. You're fat. Really fat.");
     System.out.println("You can still be a famous sumo wrestler though!");
    }
   }
   else {
    if (readier <= 18.5){
     System.out.println("You're probably gonna die of malnutrition soon. Go grab a snack.");
    }
    else if (readier <= 24.9) {
     System.out.println("You're fit and ready to get fat.");
    }
    else if (readier <= 29.9) {
     System.out.println("You're already quite fat. put that chocolate back!");
    }
    else {
     System.out.println("Oh boy. You're fat. Really fat.");
     System.out.println("You can still be a famous sumo wrestler though!");
    }
   }
   System.out.println("If you'd like to run the program again, press 'Y' and confirm.");
   System.out.println("  If you'd like to exit now, press any other key and confirm. ");
   Scanner answerscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   answer = answerscanner.next();
  } while (answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y"));
 }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look up try/catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop:

```
Scanner heightscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Define your height in centimetres.");

while(!heightScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Define your height in centimetres.");
    heightScanner.nextLine();
}
height = heightscanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Uh... That was quite easy. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks for the solution, anyway, in the code you provided, there is a mistake in naming of the scanner, though made by me primarily I guess. "Scanner heightscanner" "while(!heightScanner". Gonna edit my code so that the scanner is named heightScanner actually. :)